# Double powers: ^ does not work

Tags: math-operators

I would like to write a power on top of a power as in this sample equation:[image]

I can write **e^-{(lambda \, t)}** for the first power and then how to add the alpha exponent? LaTeX does not allow another ^.

Comment: It does, but you must contain it within the first power: `e^{-(\lambda \, t)^{\alpha}}.` After all, it is `-(\lambda \, t)` that you are raising to the power of `\alpha` (and, of course, `e` is being raised to the power of all of that)

Comment: You have to use braces: `e^{\lambda t^\alpha}`, since ^ only raises the next token with respect to the current "baseline"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Successive superscripts need to be placed inside a braced group:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  F(t) = \Pr(T \leq t) = \begin{cases}
    1 - e^{-(\lambda t)^\alpha} & \text{for $t > 0$} \\
    0                           & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the `cases*` environment from the `mathtools` package instead, as that typesets the second column in text mode.

Comment: Instead of `\[ ... \]` I always prefer `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`, that gives sequential equation numbers. If you do not want the number, the `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}`.